# htaccess redirect subdomain to one page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

I need help. 
I want to redirect all my sub domains(only sub-domains) using htaccess.

For example,

```
myRootDomain
|
|- subdomain1
|      |- page1.php
|
|- subdomain2
|       |-page2.php
|
|- sdomain.php
```

If this is my domain hierarchy, then i want to write expression in htaccess to redirect all requests of subdomain1, subdomain2 to sdomain.php.

Comment: ...if someone understood him translate please ?

Comment: as far i understand he wants to redirect a sub-domain using htaccess.

Answer (score 0):

It might help

http://www.scriptygoddess.com/archives/2007/06/13/redirect-a-subdomain-to-a-directory-using-htaccess/